# How to return secret from getSecretValue with AWS secret manager?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to get my secret from AWS secret manager with the sample code from AWS console. But At the the end of the function it returns undefined value. On the other hand when I log the secret inside getSecretValue it returns the correct value

```
    const env = require("../SharedExternalDependencies/node_modules/dotenv");
process.env.AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG = "true";
var AWS = require("../SharedExternalDependencies/node_modules/aws-sdk"),
  region = "eu-west-1",
  secretName = "********",
  secret,
  decodedBinarySecret;
exports.getCredentials = (event, context, callback) => {
  // Create a Secrets Manager client
  var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: region,
  });


  client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
      if ("SecretString" in data) {
        secret = data.SecretString;
        secret = JSON.parse(secret);
        console.log(secret) // return the correct value 
      } else {
        let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, "base64");
        decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString("ascii");
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(secret) // return undefined 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected callback behavior. I would refine it down to this:

```
var result;

callbackFunc(function(err, data) {
  // executes second, after the 'console.log' below
  result = data;
})
// executes first, before data has returned
console.log(result);
```

If you continue to work with a callback, the only way to guarantee a value is to reference the variable inside 'callbackFunc'. You *could* convert it to a promise. It's just a different syntax

```
const myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  callbackFunc(function(err, data) {
    if (err) { reject(err) }
    else { resolve(data) }
  })
})

myPromise.then(function(data) { doSomethingWithData(data) }
```